# Como remover o BOM (Byte-Order-Mark) de multiplos arquivos UTF-8?

Tags: android, android-studio, utf-8

Tenho vários arquivos em UTF-8 com a BOM(*Byte-Order-Mark*) e quero remover vários ao mesmo tempo. A necessidade é que tenho um projeto Android criado no Eclipse e preciso realizar uma migração para o Android Studio. A IDE acusa esses caracteres abaixo nas classes:

```
 ï »¿
```

Está dando milhares de erros, por conta do projeto conter nada mais nada menos que basicamente 532 classes. Para realizar esse procedimento no Android Studio versão 3, é simples, porém é um trabalho bastante arduo, por ter que fazer arquivo por arquivo. Basta ir em `File > Remove BOM`. Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria a forma mais prática de resolver isso? Como remover o BOM (*Byte-Order-Mark*) de multiplos arquivos UTF-8?

Comment: Não sei nenhum jeito pelo android studio de resolver esse problema. Mas dependendo do Sistema Operacional que você está usando, pode montar um script que automatiza o processo para todos arquivos de uma pasta.

Comment: Testei esse [projeto](https://github.com/alastairruhm/utfbom-remove) para Windows, mas tem ele pra Mac e Linux. Pra mim funcionou perfeitamente. Coloquei o programa na pasta raiz onde eu queria remover todos os BOM's e abri ele. Ele executa o programa pra pasta raiz e subpastas. Se for usar, não esqueça de antes fazer backup do seu projeto.